# d3 - drag behaviour triggered when clicking

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, drag-and-drop

In my svg container, I have a `<g>` with a rectangle and text. When dragging this group, I want to make the group disappear and just drag a small rectangle across the screen to represent the object. In order to do that, I use a `<div>` which I make visible when dragging starts. I make my svg group being dragged disappear.

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjoffily/g1g7tahv/2/).
And code here:

```
   function dragDiv2End(d) {
    console.log('ending');
    var a = d3.select(this);
    a.attr('x', initial.x).attr('y', initial.y).attr('width', initial.width).attr('height', initial.height);
    a.transition().style("opacity",1);
    d3.select('#dragid').style('visibility', 'hidden');

}

function dragDiv2Start(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    console.log('starting');
    var a = d3.select(this);
    initial = {x: a.attr('x'), y: a.attr('y'), width: a.attr('width'), height: a.attr('height')};
    a.attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0])
    .attr('y', d3.mouse(this)[1]) .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 20).style("opacity",0);

    var b = d3.select('#dragid');
    b.style({
        left: (parseInt(d3.mouse(this)[0])) + "px",
        top: d3.mouse(this)[1] + "px",
        border: "1px solid black",
        visibility: 'visible'

    });
}

function dragDiv2Move(d) {
    var b = d3.select(this);

    var a = d3.select('#dragid');
    a.transition().delay(50).style('opacity', 1);
    //console.log(d3.event.x, d3.event.y, a.style("right"));
    console.log(d3.mouse(this));
    a.style({
        left: (parseInt(d3.mouse(this)[0])) + "px",
        top: d3.mouse(this)[1] + "px"
    });
}

function doClick(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    console.log('clicked');
}
var initial = {};
var svg = d3.select('#div2').append('svg').attr('height', 300).attr('width', 300).style('border', 'solid 1px blue');

var g = svg.append('g').on('click', doClick);
g.append('rect').attr('x', 10).attr('y', 10).attr('width', 200).attr('height', 200).style('stroke', 'red').style('fill', 'white');
var text = g.append('text')
text.text('my test').attr('x', 50).attr('y', 50);

var dragDiv = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(Object)
        .on("drag", dragDivMove);

var dragDiv2 = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(Object)
        .on("dragstart", dragDiv2Start)
        .on("drag", dragDiv2Move)
        .on("dragend", dragDiv2End);
g.call(dragDiv2);
```

Trouble starts with the click event which the group should also listen to. I get this flickering effect of my svg object disappearing (behaviour of the drag event) when a simple click occurs.

I understand why it happens but this is very undesirable and I am struggling to find a solution to this problem. To see it occurring, just click and/or drag the red rectangle.

I tried preventing the event from propagating, which works fine from drag to click but not the other way around.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: you'll have to add some conditional logic in your `dragDiv2Start` function that contrains visual changes until some sort of threshold becomes true.. whether it is some sort of distance or time.

Comment: This is a very neat solution. Works really well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit and used the 'Tidy' effect in this SO code snippet. to format the synatx..

First, within your Start and Move functions.. I'm making a variable object hold the `d3.mouse(this)` data. (i.e. `var currentPosition = {"x" : d3.mouse(this)[0], "y" : d3.mouse(this)[1]};`).

What I'm doing is adding a threshold value and associating it to distance. I call on the **dragStart** method after wrapping it in an anonymous function. This allows me to take the `this` instance, as well as the `thresholdValue`, and bind it to the dragStart that I'm calling it.

```
var dragDiv2 = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(Object)
  .on("dragstart", function(arg) {
    console.log("anonymous function - arg: %o", arg);
    dragDiv2Start.bind(this.children[0], 5)();
  })
  .on("drag", dragDiv2Move)
  .on("dragend", dragDiv2End);
```

**However**, `this` is actually the element `g`.. which does not have any attributes set to it, so I'm getting the first child - which is `rect` -, and binding that to the dragStart method.

I created an object variable called 'threshold' which is assigned the `min.x`, `min.y`, `max.x`, and `max.y` values in the **dragStart** function. I also set a flag - called `IsNeeded` indicating whether the dragMove function should check against the threshold, and conditionally return or apply visual changes..  the dragEnd will simply return if `IsNeeded` is 'still' true;

I moved your visual styling from **dragStart** into **dragMove**, and I only run it at the time `threshold.isNeeded` is set to `false`.

---

### Sample Code Snippet

```js
function dragDivMove(d) {
  var a = d3.select(this);

  var data = {
    "event": {
      "dx": parseInt(d3.event.dx),
      "dy": parseInt(d3.event.dy)
    },
    select: {
      "right": parseInt(a.style("right").replace("px", "")),
      "top": parseInt(a.style("top").replace("px", ""))
    }
  };


  console.log(data);
  a.style({
    "right": (data.select.right - data.event.dx) + "px",
    "top": (data.event.dy + data.select.top) + "px"
  });
}

function dragDiv2End(d) {
  console.log('ending');
  
  var a = d3.select(this);
  var b = d3.select('#dragid');
    
  a.attr('x', initial.x)
  .attr('y', initial.y)
  .attr('width', initial.width)
  .attr('height', initial.height);
    
  a.transition().style("opacity", 1);
  b.style('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function dragDiv2Start(thresholdValue) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();  
  var a = d3.select(this);
  
  console.log('starting - this: %o , d3.select(this): %o, thresholdValue: %o', this, a, thresholdValue);


  initial = {
    "x": parseInt(a.attr('x').replace("px",0)),
    "y": parseInt(a.attr('y').replace("px",0)),
    "width": parseInt(a.attr('width').replace("px","")),
    "height": parseInt(a.attr('height').replace("px",""))
  };

  threshold.min = {
    "x": initial.x - thresholdValue,
    "y": initial.y - thresholdValue
  };
  threshold.max = {
    "x": initial.x + thresholdValue,
    "y": initial.y + thresholdValue
  };
  threshold.isNeeded = true;

  var currentPosition = {
    "x": d3.mouse(this)[0],
    "y": d3.mouse(this)[1]
  };

  console.log("current: %o, initial: %o, threshold: %o", currentPosition, initial, threshold);


}

function dragDiv2Move(d) {
  var a = d3.select('#dragid');
  var b = d3.select(this);

  var currentPosition = {
        "x": d3.mouse(this)[0],
        "y": d3.mouse(this)[1]
      };
    

  if (threshold.isNeeded) {
    if (threshold.min.x < currentPosition.x || threshold.min.y < currentPosition.y || threshold.max.x > currentPosition.x || threshold.max.y > currentPosition.y) {
      threshold.isNeeded = false;

      b.attr('x', currentPosition.x);
      b.attr('y', currentPosition.y);
      b.attr('width', 20);
      b.attr('height', 20);
      b.style("opacity", 0);

      a.style({
        "left" : currentPosition.x + "px",
        "top" : currentPosition.y + "px",
        "border" : "1px solid black",
        "visibility" : 'visible'
      });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

    console.log(currentPosition);  
  a.transition().delay(50).style('opacity', 1);
  a.style({
    "left" : currentPosition.x + "px",
    "top" : currentPosition.y + "px"
  });
}

function doClick(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
  console.log('clicked');
}

var initial = {},
  threshold = {
    "min": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "max": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "isNeeded": true
  };


var svg = d3.select('#div2').append('svg').attr('height', 300).attr('width', 300).style('border', 'solid 1px blue');

var g = svg.append('g').on('click', doClick);
g.append('rect').attr('x', 10).attr('y', 10).attr('width', 200).attr('height', 200).style('stroke', 'red').style('fill', 'white');
var text = g.append('text')
text.text('my test').attr('x', 50).attr('y', 50);

var dragDiv = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(Object)
  .on("drag", dragDivMove);

var dragDiv2 = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(Object)
  .on("dragstart", function() {
    dragDiv2Start.bind(this.children[0], 5)();
  })
  .on("drag", dragDiv2Move)
  .on("dragend", dragDiv2End);

g.call(dragDiv2);

//d3.select('#dragid').call(dragDiv);
```

```css
#dragid {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragid">
  <span></span>

</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

---

Note: there is a formula error. the initial values (of `g > rect`) are being compared to the subsequent `currentPosition` values of the mouse in **dragMove**.. It should be that the `currentPosition` values of the mouse in **dragStart** are to be compared against subsequent `currentPosition` values of the mouse in **dragMove**..

Regardlesss, It's worth noting that **dragMove** does not fire unless you actually drag with the mouse key down.. which is why the visuals do not flicker; even though, in the current implementation the `isNeeded` calculation is always satisified in **dragMove**..